# Android MediaPlayer - Which extension to use?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, native-android

I read about how to play a sound using the MediaPlayer API, however, I have no idea what file extension I should use. It is for a custom notification sound, and I'm sure MP3 could be the way to go, however I'm not sure if there's a convention to a type that is better for some reason.

I know this question might be more of an opinion base, but in any case, let me know what you guys usually use.

Comment: Perhaps flac which is lossless and supported since Android 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if there's a convention to a type that is better for some reason

No, there is not. MP3 should be fine. You can find the supported media formats in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/platform/supported-formats#audio-formats).